# Are the objects and instance variables eligible for GC if a service is destroyed?

Tags: android, memory-management, service, garbage-collection

Let's say I have a Service where I have many instance variables and objects with no static reference to them. Objects as in : many ArrayLists and Sensor objects. Now if onDestroy of my service is called, do I need to set them null explicitly or should I not worry about that ?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to do anything special. A Service is a java class as any other so all class members are garbage collected.
Please note that it is possible to hold a reference to Service (or Activity etc) even after onDestroy is called, in this case Service and its members are not destroyed. In other words onDestroy is an Android service lifecycle callback, which is a different thing from java object lifecycle.